# Renting solar panels in another state

Tags: solar-power, usa

I live in Pennsylvania in the United States. Due to a combination of frequent overcast days, potential storm damage, and my wife not wanting to cover up our recently-rebuilt roof, I'm not able to install my own solar panels, but I remembered seeing an article about a company that was essentially letting one invest in solar panels installed in sunnier states like California and Arizona (specifically ones built on rooftops there). I visited the company's website and thought I'd bookmarked it, but I cannot find the link anymore.

Do such resources currently exist? Have they proven economically feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.yeloha.com/ does this.  Since I need 30 characters to post, let me add that I'm not 100% sure they serve customers in PA, yet.

Comment: That is indeed the one I was thinking of!

Answer (score 1):

Living in PA you should consider solar thermal and bio-mass for your energy needs.

Solar thermal panels such as the evacuated tube type systems and bio-mass boilers will offer you the best home energy efficiency because of your geography.

If it is electrical energy you are most concerned about and you have already resolved the sustainability of your heat demand (the highest demand and the highest cost) - you should look to first: reduce energy consumption using LED lighting and low energy appliances.
THEN; you can consider a number of products that make electricity from heat taken from bio-mass boilers. (Particularly available in central and northern states).

If you are near to the local electricity network - ask your local network operator in a few months whether there is any subsidy for electric generated this way. They may offer you an export meter and pay you extra for making energy this way for your neighbours [Tax Credits upto 30%](http://www.dasolar.com/energytaxcredit-rebates-grants/pennsylvania).

Following the latest negotiations in Paris COP21 the USA along with most other countries will be working on more bio-mass based incentives so look out for them and plan for them in your home energy strategies.